# in vue.js copy data successfully click on text box but not passing validation

Tags: php, validation, vue.js, element

I am trying to copy the value of one text to another on clicking on checkbox. value copy successfully but it not pass validation. so please resolve my issue.. and even one more issue..I want to validate some textbox to numbur and regex how do I do that using same validation format which I follow.please give me example.in above example in pincode validation i want that user use only numbers. and 1st number is not 0 so how I can do that

I am using tab form of vue-wizard. I am attaching the image of error so check this out too.
[image]

```
<tab-content title="OFFICE ADDRESS" icon="ti-settings" :before-change="validateSecondStep">

    <el-form :inline="true" :model="formInline2" class="demo-form-inline" :rules="rules2" ref="ruleForm2">

    <el-form-item label="Business Address : " prop=""></el-form-item>
    <br>

    <el-form-item label="Address 1" prop="addr1">
          <el-input id="addr1" maxlength="35" v-model="formInline2.addr1" placeholder="Address 1"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>

        <el-form-item label="Address 2" prop="addr2">
          <el-input id="addr2" maxlength="35" v-model="formInline2.addr2" placeholder="Address 2"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <br>

        <el-form-item label="City/Town/Village" prop="ctv">
          <el-input id="ctv" v-model="formInline2.ctv" placeholder="City/Town/Village"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>


        <el-form-item label="Landmark" prop="lmark">
          <el-input id="lmark" maxlength="30" v-model="formInline2.lmark" placeholder="Landmark"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>


        <el-form-item label="Post Office" prop="poff">
          <el-input id="poff" maxlength="30" v-model="formInline2.poff" placeholder="Post Office"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <br>

        <el-form-item label="Pincode" prop="pinc">
          <el-input id="pinc" maxlength="6" v-model="formInline2.pinc" placeholder="Pincode"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <br>

        <el-form-item label="City" prop="city">
          <el-input id="city" maxlength="30" v-model="formInline2.city" placeholder="City"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>


        <el-form-item label="State" prop="state">
          <el-input id="state" maxlength="30" v-model="formInline2.state" placeholder="State"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <br>


        <el-form-item label="Residence Address : " prop=""></el-form-item>
    <br>
    <el-form-item label="" prop="sameaddr"> 
    <el-checkbox-group v-model="formInline2.sameaddr">
      <el-checkbox label="click and populate if its same as business address" name="sameaddr" v-on:change="copyAddress(formInline2.sameaddr)"></el-checkbox>  
    </el-checkbox-group>
  </el-form-item>
  <br>
    <!-- <div v-if="formInline2.sameaddr == true"> -->

    <el-form-item label="Address 1" prop="raddr1">
          <el-input id="raddr1" maxlength="35" v-model="formInline2.raddr1" placeholder="Address 1"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>

        <el-form-item label="Address 2" prop="raddr2">
          <el-input id="raddr2" maxlength="35" v-model="formInline2.raddr2" placeholder="Address 2"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <br>

        <el-form-item label="City/Town/Village" prop="rctv">
          <el-input id="rctv" v-model="formInline2.rctv" placeholder="City/Town/Village"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>


        <el-form-item label="Landmark" prop="rlmark">
          <el-input id="rlmark" maxlength="30" v-model="formInline2.rlmark" placeholder="Landmark"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>


        <el-form-item label="Post Office" prop="rpoff">
          <el-input id="rpoff" maxlength="30" v-model="formInline2.rpoff" placeholder="Post Office"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <br>

        <el-form-item label="Pincode" prop="rpinc">
          <el-input id="rpinc" maxlength="6" v-model="formInline2.rpinc" placeholder="Pincode"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
        <br>

        <el-form-item label="City" prop="rcity">
          <el-input id="rcity" maxlength="30" v-model="formInline2.rcity" placeholder="City"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>


        <el-form-item label="State" prop="rstate">
          <el-input id="rstate" maxlength="30" v-model="formInline2.rstate" placeholder="State"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>



    </el-form>


    </tab-content>

<script>
const app= new Vue({
   el: '#app',
     data() {
       return {
formInline2: {
         addr1:'',
         addr2:'',
         ctv:'',
         lmark:'',
         poff:'',
         pinc:'',
         city:'',
         state:'',
         sameaddr:false,
         raddr1:'',
         raddr2:'',
         rctv:'',
         rlmark:'',
         rpoff:'',
         rpinc:'',
         rcity:'',
         rstate:''
         },

         rules2: {
          addr1: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter Address 1',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 35,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 35',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           addr2: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter Address 2',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 35,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 35',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           ctv: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter City/Town/Village',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           lmark: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter Landmark',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 30,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 30',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           poff: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter Post Office',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 30,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 30',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           pinc: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter Pincode',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 6,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 6',
             trigger: 'blur'
           },],
           city: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter City',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 30,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 30',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           state: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter State',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 30,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 30',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],

           raddr1: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter Address 1',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 35,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 35',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           raddr2: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter Address 2',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 35,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 35',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           rctv: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter City/Town/Village',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           rlmark: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter Landmark',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 30,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 30',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           rpoff: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter Post Office',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 30,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 30',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           rpinc: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter Pincode',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 6,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 6',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           rcity: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter City',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 30,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 30',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }],
           rstate: [{
             required: true,
             message: 'Please enter State',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }, {
             max: 30,
             message: 'Length should not be more than 30',
             trigger: 'blur'
           }]
         },
}
 methods: {
         onComplete: function() {
           alert('Yay. Done!');
         },
         copyAddress: function(chk){
           //console.log(chk);
             if(chk == true){
            var addr1 = document.getElementById('addr1').value;
            document.getElementById('raddr1').value = addr1;
           // console.log(addr1);

            var addr2 = document.getElementById('addr2').value;
            document.getElementById('raddr2').value = addr2;
            //console.log(addr2);

            var ctv = document.getElementById('ctv').value;
            document.getElementById('rctv').value = ctv;
           // console.log(ctc);

            var lmark = document.getElementById('lmark').value;
            document.getElementById('rlmark').value = lmark;
          //  console.log(lmark);

            var poff = document.getElementById('poff').value;
            document.getElementById('rpoff').value = poff;
          //  console.log(poff);

            var pinc = document.getElementById('pinc').value;
            document.getElementById('rpinc').value = pinc;
           // console.log(pinc);

            var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
            document.getElementById('rcity').value = city;
           // console.log(city);

            var state = document.getElementById('state').value;
            document.getElementById('rstate').value = state;
           // console.log(state);



            }else{
              document.getElementById('raddr1').value = "";
              document.getElementById('raddr2').value = "";
              document.getElementById('rctv').value = "";
              document.getElementById('rlmark').value = "";
              document.getElementById('rpoff').value = "";
              document.getElementById('rpinc').value = "";
              document.getElementById('rcity').value = "";
              document.getElementById('rstate').value = "";
            }
         },
</script>
```

Comment: There are two unrelated questions here. They should be asked separately.

Comment: you understood @skirtle so please try to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `validate` on the `el-form`. For more details of the validation methods see:

https://element.eleme.io/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/en-US/component/form#form-methods

In my example I've removed the ids and direct DOM manipulation. You can perform the copying just within the data itself.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      formInline2: {
        addr1: '',
        sameaddr: false,
        raddr1: ''
      },

      rules2: {
        addr1: [{
          required: true,
          message: 'Please enter Address 1',
          trigger: 'blur'
        }, {
          max: 35,
          message: 'Length should not be more than 35',
          trigger: 'blur'
        }],
        raddr1: [{
          required: true,
          message: 'Please enter Address 1',
          trigger: 'blur'
        }, {
          max: 35,
          message: 'Length should not be more than 35',
          trigger: 'blur'
        }]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    copyAddress (chk) {
      const form = this.formInline2;
      
      if (chk) {
        form.raddr1 = form.addr1;
      } else {
        form.raddr1 = '';
      }
      
      this.$refs.ruleForm2.validate()
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui@2.10.1/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui@2.10.1/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-form :inline="true" :model="formInline2" class="demo-form-inline" :rules="rules2" ref="ruleForm2">

    <el-form-item label="Business Address : " prop=""></el-form-item>
    <br>

    <el-form-item label="Address 1" prop="addr1">
      <el-input maxlength="35" v-model="formInline2.addr1" placeholder="Address 1"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>
    <br>


    <el-form-item label="Residence Address : " prop=""></el-form-item>
    <br>
    <el-form-item label="" prop="sameaddr">
      <el-checkbox-group v-model="formInline2.sameaddr">
        <el-checkbox label="click and populate if its same as business address" name="sameaddr" v-on:change="copyAddress(formInline2.sameaddr)"></el-checkbox>
      </el-checkbox-group>
    </el-form-item>
    <br>

    <el-form-item label="Address 1" prop="raddr1">
      <el-input maxlength="35" v-model="formInline2.raddr1" placeholder="Address 1"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>
  </el-form>

</div>
```